# Get Swift enum type from string that matches type, not rawValue

Tags: swift, enums

I'm using a third-party library that has an enum class defining some Media Device Types. I also have an API that can provide the Media Device Type to the Swift code as a string. I need to somehow get the Media Device Type *from* that string, so that I can pass it to another method.

**Third-Party Enum**

```swift
@objc public enum MediaDeviceType: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
    case audioBluetooth
    case audioWiredHeadset
    case audioBuiltInSpeaker
    case audioHandset
    case videoFrontCamera
    case videoBackCamera
    case other

    public var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .audioBluetooth:
            return "audioBluetooth"
        case .audioWiredHeadset:
            return "audioWiredHeadset"
        case .audioBuiltInSpeaker:
            return "audioBuiltInSpeaker"
        case .audioHandset:
            return "audioHandset"
        case .videoFrontCamera:
            return "videoFrontCamera"
        case .videoBackCamera:
            return "videoBackCamera"
        case .other:
            return "other"
        }
    }
}
```

**Things I've Tried:**

As you can see, the `.rawValue` is an `Int` which means that I can't access the value using the initialiser for the enum:

```swift
let stringType = "audioBluetooth"
let type = MediaDeviceType(rawValue: stringType)
```

This gives me the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int'

I thought that maybe I could `switch` the `stringType` and return the correct media device type, but it seems that it doesn't actually work as expected when passing to the next method along.

```swift
private func getMediaTypeStringToEnum(type: String) -> MediaDeviceType? {
    switch (type) {
    case "audioBluetooth":
      return .audioBluetooth
    case "audioWiredHeadset":
      return .audioWiredHeadset
    case "audioBuiltInSpeaker":
      return .audioBuiltInSpeaker
    case "audioHandset":
      return .audioHandset
    case "videoFrontCamera":
      return .videoFrontCamera
    case "videoBackCamera":
      return .videoBackCamera
    case "other":
      return .other
    default:
      return nil
    }
  }
```

The next method takes two parameters, a `String`, and an optional MediaDeviceType. If the second parameter doesn't match, the method switches the `init` method. [Documentation](https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-ios/blob/master/AmazonChimeSDK/AmazonChimeSDK/device/MediaDevice.swift).

My basic implementation:

```swift
let stringType = "audioBluetooth"
let label = "Media Device Label"
let hopefullyEnumType = getMediaTypeStringToEnum(stringType)
let mediaDevice = MediaDevice(label, hopefullyEnumType)
```

---

I'm *very* new to Swift, so maybe there's something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't actually work as expected when passing to the next method along"? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Are you really using Swift3? If so, why? Swift 5.3 is the latest version.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Sorry I must've clicked that one by accident

Comment: @Sweeper added my basic implementation

Comment: `hopefullyEnumType` is an optional. You need to unwrap it before you can pass it into `init`, which takes a non-optional.

Comment: Right okay, so maybe something like this: 
```guard let enumType = getMediaTypeStringToEnum(type: mediaType) else { throw MeetingModelError.invalidAudioDevice }```

Comment: It turns out my `switch` solution was correct, but the third-party library was storing a reference to media devices it had already detected, so when I tried to make a new one from the `String` it didn't match the internal device stored in memory, so wouldn't select it. My solution to this problem was to get all the internal devices and `.first` them where a label matched. This then gave me the in-memory device.

Answer (score 1):

If you are absolutely sure that the enum cases will not be extended with new cases in the future, then one solution would be to iterate through all and see which ones match:

```swift
private func getMediaTypeStringToEnum(type: String) -> MediaDeviceType? {
    let allMediaTypes: [MediaDeviceType] = [.audioBluetooth, .audioWiredHeadset, .audioBuiltInSpeaker, .audioHandset, .videoFrontCamera, .videoBackCamera, .other]
    return allMediaTypes.first { $0.description == type }
}
```

If you're not sure, then you'll have to keep an eye on the enum declaration, and add the new cases to the `allMediaTypes` array when that happens.

Ofcourse, if the enum would've been `CaseIterable`, then your problem would be less easier to solve, and would not require maintaining the code:

```swift
private func getMediaTypeStringToEnum(type: String) -> MediaDeviceType? {
    MediaDeviceType.allCases.first { $0.description == type }
}
```

As a side note, you could also implement a failable initializer over the enum, this should make the solution easier to use, and more cohesive with the enum:

```
extension MediaDeviceType {
    init?(string: String) {
        // do your thing
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually very similar to something that I ended up doing, thanks! The problem wasn't actually anything to do with the enum, it was to do with the third-party SDK storing the specific MediaDevice in memory, but that's not documented. Creating a new MediaDevice wouldn't be valid. Frustrating, going to post an issue on their GitHub about it.

Answer (score 0):

swiftly code is:

```
@objc public enum MediaDeviceType: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
case audioBluetooth
case audioWiredHeadset
case audioBuiltInSpeaker
case audioHandset
case videoFrontCamera
case videoBackCamera
case other

init(from string: String) {
    switch (string) {
        case "audioBluetooth":
            self = .audioBluetooth
        case "audioWiredHeadset":
            self = .audioWiredHeadset
        case "audioBuiltInSpeaker":
            self = .audioBuiltInSpeaker
        case "audioHandset":
            self = .audioHandset
        case "videoFrontCamera":
            self = .videoFrontCamera
        case "videoBackCamera":
            self = .videoBackCamera
        default:
            self = .other
        }
}

public var description: String {
    switch self {
    case .audioBluetooth:
        return "audioBluetooth"
    case .audioWiredHeadset:
        return "audioWiredHeadset"
    case .audioBuiltInSpeaker:
        return "audioBuiltInSpeaker"
    case .audioHandset:
        return "audioHandset"
    case .videoFrontCamera:
        return "videoFrontCamera"
    case .videoBackCamera:
        return "videoBackCamera"
    case .other:
        return "other"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I wouldn't be able to update the third-party SDK code